# Convert JSON string to Key / Value Arrays

Tags: code-golf, array, javascript, json

Convert JSON (key/value pairs) to two native arrays, one array of keys and another of values, in your language.

```
var X = '{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c","d":"d","e":"e","f":"f9","g":"g2","h":"h1"}';
```

The value array could be an array of strings or integers.

So we need two functions **keys** & **vals**, returning native arrays on input of JSON string.

In above example the output would be:

```
keys : ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
vals : ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f9", "g2", "h1"]
```

Here is my attempt at this using javascript:

**keys** : (53 Chars)

```
function keys(X){return X.match(/[a-z0-9]+(?=":)/gi)}
```

**vals** : (56 Chars)

```
function vals(X){return X.match(/[a-z0-9]+(?="[,}])/gi)}
```

Can other languages challenge this??

Comment: What assumptions are you making about the input? You seem to be assuming that it's a single JSON object all of whose member values are strings, and none of whose names or values require escaping. Those assumptions seem to be rather unmotivated / arbitrary.

Comment: I know. But you could say it's a JSON with some constraints. It need not be arbitrary since we could find such cases a lot, in a practical data set. Besides, answers handling the general set would be more than welcome... (as in one of the answers)

Comment: `function keys(x){return Object.keys(JSON.parse(x))}`...

Comment: I'd VTRO (edit: it's not closed, so I'd not-vote-to-close) this, but there's still a few things that are unclear: Can we have a single function that returns both arrays? What can we assume the keys or values look like? What is a "native array"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Python, 27/30

To actually comply with the rules:

```
keys=lambda x:list(eval(x))
vals=lambda x:eval(x).values()
```

#### Python, 30

Just using one function:

```
lambda x:zip(*eval(x).items())
```

This will separate the keys from the values and return them in a list.

#### Python, 7

If returning a dictionary is allowed, then this is all you need:

```
eval(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

### APL 32

Index origin 1. If you will accept the keys and values being returned as a two row array then a simple one liner will do the job in APL. This takes screen input via ←⍞

```
⍉((.5×⍴j),2)⍴j←(~j∊'{":;,}')⊂j←⍞
```

Taking the given example as input:

```
{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c","d":"d","e":"e","f":"f9","g":"g2","h":"h1"};

a b c d e f  g  h
a b c d e f9 g2 h1
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 28 bytes

Instead of 2 separate functions to return keys and values, I'm returning both in the form of a `hash`.

```
sub j2h{eval pop=~y/:"/,/dr}
```

Sample usage:

```
$_='{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c","d":"d","e":"e","f":"f9","g":"g2","h":"h1"}';
%h=j2h($_);
print $h{f}; # prints f9
print $h{g}; # prints g2
```

It even works for arbitrarily deeply nested variables:

```
$_='{"a":{"b":{"c":"c3","d":"d4"},"c":"c5"},"b":"b6"}';
%h=j2h($_);
print $h{a}{b}{d}; # prints d4
print $h{a}{c};    # prints c5
```

Answer (score 2):

## Tcl 69,69

first attempt 132 keys+vals

```
proc j {x n} {
regsub -all {(".*?"):(".*?")} $x "\[lappend o \\$n\]" x
subst $x
set o $o
}
proc keys x {j $x 1}
proc vals x {j $x 2}
```

second try 69 keys, 69 values

```
proc keys x {regsub -all {(".*?"):(".*?").} $x {\1 } x
lindex $x\} 0}

proc vals x {regsub -all {(".*?"):(".*?").} $x {\2 } x
lindex $x\} 0}
```

Comment: Compared to the answers, this one is very, very long. Is there a way you can compact this down, to (say) less than 50 characters?

Comment: 69 per proc is the best I could get. It looks like Johannes Kuhn has a good one for Tcl 8.6.

Comment: You can shorten a bit because you are regex' tagging expressions you don't need, so you can remove some `()`: http://rextester.com/EFMSXX16344

Comment: May be I am wrong, but I think you also don't need ` 0` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## K, 22

```
{+`$":"\:'","\:1_-1_x}
```

The double quotes in the input string have to be escaped

```
k){+`$":"\:'","\:1_-1_x} "{\"a\":\"a\",\"b\":\"b\",\"c\":\"c\",\"d\":\"d\",\"e\":\"e\",\"f\":\"f9\",\"g\":\"g2\",\"h\":\"h1\"}"
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"  "g"  "h"
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f9" "g2" "h1"
```

For the same bytecount you could just read from stdin

```
+`$":"\:'","\:1_-1_0:0
```

.

```
k)+`$":"\:'","\:1_-1_0:0
{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c","d":"d","e":"e","f":"f9","g":"g2","h":"h1"}
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"  "g"  "h"
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f9" "g2" "h1"
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 56/58

Pssh, PHP has functions for this stuff (although it won't win the shortest answer award).

```
function keys($j){return array_keys(json_decode($j,1));}
function vals($j){return array_values(json_decode($j,1));}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Prints list of keys, then returns list of values.

```apl
'⍎¨⎕←⎕NL¯2'⍎⍨⎕JSON
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X/1Rb9@hFY/6pj5qmwAk/XwOrTcCiT3qBQl6Bfv7/U8DSQFF@qZ6@j/qaj603vhR20QgLzjIGUiGeHgG/09Tr1ZKVLICYh2lJCCdBKSTgXQykE4B0ilAOhVIpwLpNCCdZglkpAMZ6UZARgaQkWGoVKsOAA)

`⎕JSON` convert JSON string to APL namespace object

`'`…`'⍎⍨` in that namespace, execute the following code:

`⎕NL¯2` name list for all all variables

`⎕←` print that list

`⍎¨` execute each name

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <s>34/36</s> 28/28  bytes

-14 bytes total thanks to @mazzy!

To fetch the keys:

```
&(gcm *F*son)"$args" -a|% k*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBDkAwFEXRrTQ/KA0DZizAPtqqNlEqOjDA2r83uDn3TLe7cnAxMle1t7tQs8rpaKjQl88kOv2WYlPMLB/SNKGWDDTQQgsXuEAHHVzhOmI8xg@YgAk9ffIH)

To fetch the values:

```
&(gcm *F*son)"$args" -a|% v*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBDkAwFEXRrTQ/KA0DZizAPtqqdlAqmjDA2r83uDn3SLc7c3AxMle1t5tQs8ppb6jQp88kOv2W4lLMLB/SNKGWDDTQQgsXuEAHHVzhOmI8xg@YgAk9ffIH)

Kinda cheap, as it uses the built-in method `ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable` to convert the data from JSON.

Comment: [keys](https://tio.run/##DcZBDkAwFEXRrTQ/KA0DZizAPtqqNlEqOjDA2r83uDn3TLe7cnAxMle1t7tQs8rpaKjQl88kOv2WYlPMLB/SNKGWDDTQQgsXuEAHHVzhOmI8xg@YgAk9ffIH "PowerShell – Try It Online") and [values](https://tio.run/##DcZBDkAwFEXRrTQ/KA0DZizAPtqqdlAqmjDA2r83uDn3SLc7c3AxMle1t5tQs8ppb6jQp88kOv2W4lLMLB/SNKGWDDTQQgsXuEAHHVzhOmI8xg@YgAk9ffIH "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript

I'm surprised no one has proposed a better ECMAScript solution, so here's my simple attempt:

**keys**: (29 chars)

```js
X=>Object.keys(JSON.parse(X))
```

**values**: (31 chars)

```js
X=>Object.values(JSON.parse(X))
```

Comment: 28 bytes, 30 bytes: `X=>Object.keys(eval("1,"+X))`, `X=>Object.values(eval("1,"+X))`

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Much better than my solution 

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 103 bytes

```c
char*b[99],**o,*l;f(s,n)char*s;{for(o=b;*s++;l=*s-34?l:++n%4?s+1:(*o++=strndup(l,s-l)));*o=0;return b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBda4MwFIbv/RUhMJYPBdv1onqQ/o1BKUVTP8KyWIx2DPGvz504KZQxdq6e8@Y9eZOjolqpeVZN3onimCSnUIg2FAYq5kLLF93BWLUda7MChJMSTCZc9LI7mFRK@7Q7OLlJmWilzFzf2ctwZSZ0keGcg2izGLqyHzpLCphmbXvynmvLeDAGBMsHEG2vQ3/cx/EJFrEue8cWkUOwKIiO0bfy06WUw31SCOI1kpHqxx@S7XqMLyZs9Wg0eB8QoYFoKfliuV8s9GPOLTdD@SsJ1Yek@I8k7/s/aV1KDME033AHrzj5PNKcpjTf0JAWCIUHhaA8XBAuHsozfgab8oxR2FfIVYKFXCPXW4QGodnQ6UtVJq/dHH18Aw)

Usage:

`f(input, 2)` returns an array with the keys

`f(input, 0)` returns an array with the values

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 67 bytes

```c
*l;f(*s,n){for(;*s++;l=*s-34?l:++n%4?s+1:printf("%.*ls\n",s-l,l));}
```

Writes the output to stdout instead of returning arrays.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BTsMwEEX3OYVlFNV2kqot3RBTegEOgERQ5Tp2YmHcKk6KUJSrE9yxugAxi9G8rz/2H1lIK1wzz8xyTZjPHR31qSOc@Szjdsd8cb/d2zLLXLrd@2xdnjvjek1wumTWVw7nvrC5pZRP851x0g61Qo@@r81p2T4lvyRrjlctCQ@gD2EcocmYoFBXwbjz0L@@oR16xhfRoZcwLcYKiwqXoa8rnFf4CHCMIAFkhBqgjqAO7@oLBHW4CAuaBtYPoYAb4GYD0AK0YXtaYA6ZbndCrpAljdfGnJQn0TT0nmAWfvOsxDRuagKeHG3@2EKUQf1nXN2MneqHzqEVT6b5W2orGj8Xnz8)

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 11–∞ bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fck7CoAwEEXRrcjUQdDObCWkyD@ojQQFkaxdr8W8c2HW432fLd1N/6OGy@1natqMxtrOS5xoTolHjwEDRoyYMGHGvBCFKDNRiTpJ/wA)

This answer will take some refining, as I'm not yet clear on the rules. It states that two functions are required, but jq doesn't have functions and I don't know how much of our current meta consensus applies to such old posts

The essence is in two snippets:

- keys: `keys`
- values: `[.[]]`

These are both valid jq programs that each give their respective piece. Counted like this we have 11 bytes. We can also do:

```
# Return an array of arrays as [keys, values]
[keys, [.[]]]
```

```
# Return another nice JSON as {"keys": keys, "values": values}
{keys:keys, values:[.[]]}
```

I'll add a bit more explanation when the final entry is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

## CoffeeScript:

```
vals = []
keys = []
vals.push(v) and keys.push(k) for own k, v of JSON.parse(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Ruby, 19**

`eval X.gsub':','=>'`

Similar, unsurprisingly, to the Perl solution. The Ruby 1.9 literal for a `Hash` would be identical to the input form if it weren't for the quoted keys; as it is we just need to convert the colons to `=>`.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua

```
function keys(x)return loadstring("return"..x:gsub(':".-"',''))()end
function vals(x)return loadstring("return"..x:gsub('"[^"]*":',''))()end
```

68 and 71 chars

Answer (score 0):

### Tcl 8.6, 82

```
 package r json;lmap keys [dict k [set d [json::json2dict $X]]] vals [dict v $d] {}
```

The Tcl core is (unlike php) very small.
This requires the tcllib, which is available as package for most linux distributions.
I use this library because too much languages have a json_parse build in.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP 7.4+](https://www.php.net/), 39/41 bytes

([demo](https://3v4l.org/b7nDL))

The keys via closure with PHP7.4 arrow function syntax: 39 bytes

```
(fn()=>array_keys(json_decode($X,1)))()
```

The values via closure with PHP7.4 arrow function syntax: 41 bytes

```
(fn()=>array_values(json_decode($X,1)))()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3 (Total 35 characters)**

*Input JSON String*

```
X = '{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c","d":"d","e":"e","f":"f9","g":"g2","h":"h1"}'
```

**Get Keys(16 characters)**

```
k=eval(X).keys()
```

**Get Values(18 characters)**

```
v=eval(X).values()
```

[Try online](https://tio.run/##PchNCoAgGIThfacQNylEUK0KukdbrS8No6IfQaKz20DQYnheZgunXZcqdqxl6c0Vb7CMa6hhD3s4wAESJDjCsUYYhCkRFmEL/qTRteTVLDqZOwqHkIn/D3ARrrjt03IKJ5MvvIwv)

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 12 bytes

```
'";;:an2cou[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxDoAgEAXRq5BtaGikE@I9TKxgWaAwGjVUxrOvv5i8yePe5bmGqFqKMaTD8zk21dUsxr6UKCBHGWbIkGGBBQoUWGGdMQ3TPKZj@kSf/QE)

```
'";; # Split by "s
:an  # Filter by alphanumeric
2co  # Group in pairs
u[   # Unzip giving array of vals and array of keys
```